# Null parameters when calling a JAX-WS Web Service from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, xml, web-services

I have a JAX-WS web service that is working fine when it gets called from any clients (i.e. Java destkop application) but not from JavaScript.

My WS interface looks like this:

```
@WebService
public interface LicenseService {

    @WebMethod
    String getLicense(
            @WebParam(name="coupon") String coupon,
            @WebParam(name="licenseCode") String licenseCode,
            @WebParam(name="secret") String secret);
    }
```

and I call it from javascript like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", url, false);

request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
request.send(envelope);
```

and the sent `envelope` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <getLicense xmlns="http://ws.licenseman.elevelcbt.eu/">
            <coupon>SYcj1J9I</coupon>
            <licenseCode>BEPRO</licenseCode>
            <secret>1234567890</secret>
        </getLicense>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The method gets called (I can track on the Java side) but all passed parameters are null. There must be something wrong on my `envelope` format/contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it.
I needed to change my `envelope` format to look like this (I got it by tracing the raw xml message when successfully calling the WS from java client):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header />
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:getLicense xmlns:ns1="http://ws.licenseman.elevelcbt.eu/">
            <coupon>1111</coupon>
            <licenseCode>BEPRO</licenseCode>
            <secret>xxxxxxx</secret>
        </ns1:getLicense>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

It seems JAX-WS doesn't like method declaration like this:

```
<getLicense xmlns="http://ws.licenseman.elevelcbt.eu/">
```

and wants it like that:

```
<ns1:getLicense xmlns:ns1="http://ws.licenseman.elevelcbt.eu/">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! After spending hours in this issue, I fixed the problem doing what you suggest. Except that I only added this "ns1" in the tags instead of change "soap:Envelope" by "SOAP-ENV:Envelope", for example, and make the other modifications.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm having the same issue. The C# clients are going completely crazy since they generate their requests like in your issue.