# Trying to find out why one of those two SOAP requests does not work (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have a running JAX-WS webservice which already has some working endpoints. Now I'm having the following issue:

I'm having two different SOAP Requests here and I don't understand why the first one works but the second one does not.

The only obvious difference in the requests is that the first one specifies a namespace in the `<Envelope>` tag while the second one specifies it when calling the method `<getMoldDataHistory>`.

**SOAP Request 1 - Not Working (Namespace is specified at the method call)**

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>
    <s:Body
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    >
        <getMoldDataHistory
            xmlns="http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/">
            <machineId>92623-15853588</machineId>
            <start>0</start>
            <end>0</end>
        </getMoldDataHistory>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**SOAP Request 2 - Working (Namespace is specified in the `<Envelope>` tag)**

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:his="http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/">

   <soapenv:Header/>

   <soapenv:Body>
      <his:getMoldDataHistory>
         <machineId>92623-15853588</machineId>
         <start>0</start>
         <end>0</end>
      </his:getMoldDataHistory>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**The SOAP error message I'm getting when making the first (Not working) request.**

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</faultstring>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

**The stacktrace of the exception thrown from the Server when receiving the first SOAP request.**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So I'm basically trying to figure out why the first request is not working despite it being a valid SOAP request. Is there anything I need to configure at my server to allow such requests?

**EDIT:**

After doing some more testing I found out that the position of the namespace declaration does NOT matter IF the method I call has 0 parameters. As soon as parameter is required it stops working.

**EDIT 2:**

Now I stumpled upon [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296233/null-parameters-when-calling-a-jax-ws-web-service-from-javascript) . I have the same issue. My C# Client who makes the requests does not use the namespace int the method TAG. After I add it it works.

Still how can I tell JAX-WS to deal with this.

**Does not work:**

```
<getMoldDataHistory xmlns="http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/">
```

**Works:**

```
<his:getMoldDataHistory xmlns:his="http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/">
```

Answer (score 2):

When using a prefix bound to a namespace like in

```xml
<his:getMoldDataHistory xmlns:his="http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/">
    <machineId>92623-15853588</machineId>
    <start>0</start>
    <end>0</end>
</his:getMoldDataHistory>
```

then only the element `getMoldDataHistory` is put into the specified namespace. The reason is that the syntax `xmlns:his="..."` only declares the prefix. This then must used at *all elements* that you want to be in the specified namespace. In this code snippet, the only element is `getMoldDataHistory`.

Using the `xmlns="..."` syntax like in

```xml
<getMoldDataHistory xmlns="http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/">
    <machineId>92623-15853588</machineId>
    <start>0</start>
    <end>0</end>
</getMoldDataHistory>
```

not only declares the namespace, but also puts the associated element and *all child elements* into this namespace.

**Conclusion:** These two XML snippets are not semantically equivalent.

If there was such a thing as an "expanded element name" syntax, then these XML snippets would look like ...

First one:

```xml
<{http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/}getMoldDataHistory>
    <{}machineId>92623-15853588</{}machineId>
    <{}start>0</{}start>
    <{}end>0</{}end>
</{http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/}getMoldDataHistory>
```

Second one:

```xml
<{http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/}getMoldDataHistory>
    <{http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/}machineId>92623-15853588</{http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/}machineId>
    <{http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/}start>0</{http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/}start>
    <{http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/}end>0<{/http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/}end>
</{http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/}getMoldDataHistory>
```