# JAX-WS not accepting "xmlns=..." in TAGs

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jax-ws

My JAX-WS server is not accepting XML tags that do not contain the namespace-prefix.

**Does not work:**

```
<getMoldDataHistory xmlns="http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/">
```

**Works:**

```
<his:getMoldDataHistory xmlns:his="http://history.production.soap.webservices.product.company.at/">
```

How can I change my server to accept both of those variations?

Comment: These two XML elements are semantically equivalent. I doubt that any "JAX-WS server" or - better - any XML parsing tool treats them as different. Maybe you did not show the complete XML, and the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: Hello, thanks for paying attention. This question came up from my previous question where I nailed down the problem to the fact described in this post which contains the full requetss and responses: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321209/trying-to-find-out-why-one-of-those-two-soap-requests-does-not-work-java-lang-i

Comment: I answered your other question.

Comment: I saw it thanks a lot. Ill try again when Im back at work tomorrow. Im still unsure why my jax-ws backend cant deal with it.